# How to add action button in notification in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I need action button on notification in xamarin ios [here is example of action button i need to implement in xamarin ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxinR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by adding `custom actions` to a custom UI.This is done by implementing a second version of the `DidReceiveNotification` method that includes a completion handler like below:

```
        [Export ("didReceiveNotificationResponse:completionHandler:")]
        public void DidReceiveNotification (UNNotificationResponse response, Action<UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption> completionHandler)
        {

            // Update UI when the user interacts with the
            // Notification
            Server.PostEventResponse += (response) {
                // Take action based on the response
                switch(response.ActionIdentifier){
                case "accept":
                    EventResponse.Text = "Going!";
                    EventResponse.TextColor = UIColor.Green;
                    break;
                case "decline":
                    EventResponse.Text = "Not Going.";
                    EventResponse.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
                    break;
                }

                // Close Notification
                completionHandler (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption.Dismiss);
            };
        }
```

For more details and implementation steps,you could refer to our [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos).